# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'n' when using dateutil

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I am using dateutil rrule function .. i get the weekdays from my data model in django. when i put it in rrule function like this

```
for x in lgs:
    teams = Team.objects.filter(league=x.id)
    teamcount = len(teams)
    playdays = "rrule." + str(x.play_days)
    fixdays = rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY,byweekday = (playdays),dtstart=startdate,until=endate)
    print list(fixdays)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 5, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/dateutil/rrule.py", line 345, in __init__
    elif not wday.n or freq > MONTHLY:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'n'
```

if i use the function normally, and replace line 5 with

```
    fixdays = rrule.rrule(rrule.DAILY,byweekday = (rrule.SU, rrule.MO),dtstart=startdate,until=endate)
```

i get no problem. what could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(rrule.SU, rrule.MO)
```

is a list (tuple) of `dateutil.rrule.weekday` objects, while

```
"rrule." + str(x.play_days)
```

is a string (that does not have the `.n` attribute).

You could define a dictionary:

```
weekday = {'MO': rrule.MO, 'TU': rrule.TU, … }
```

and then call it:

```
playdays = weekday[str(x.play_days)]
```

Also, remember that

```
byweekday = (playdays)
```

is the same as

```
byweekday = playdays
```

If you want to define a tuple from single element, add comma:

```
byweekday = (playdays,)
```

Answer (score 1):

"rrule." + str(x.play_days) returns a string not the variable with that name, while in your hardcoded example you're passing a set of variables

You probably want to do something like this instead:

```
playdays = [getattr(rrule, pd) for pd in x.play_days]
```

and then pass playdays to byweekday without the brackets, like byweekday=playdays, .....
as eumiro said in his answer it's not necessary :)

Comment: thankyou, let me try this, this might help me solve the problem